# Angular 4 Production Deployment Workflow

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack, angular-cli

I have a lengthy discussion with a colleague about how we should deploy our angular 4 app to production server.

Would like practical advise and guide on this issue from the community, if possible.

**Premise 1**
At production server,

```
git pull
npm install
{set up production configuration}
ng build --prod --aot
```

- build and compile on production server
- production server hardware specs need to support the build process
- addition space required on hosting server to house node_modules
- git repo master branch does not have compiled codes, therefore is a "clean source repo"

**Premise 2**
At production server,

```
git pull
```

- build and compile production codes on local development workstation will be faster
- git repo master branch will keep snapshot of the compiled codes for deployment
- production server remains as a 128MB RAM with limited space, since it is to serve html, js and css.
- faster deployment to another server when required for recovery or scaling, since it is only a git pull

Comment: What's the mechanism you use to deploy? Is continuous integration(CI) implemented? If yes what's used to CI?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend either of those options, to be honest - it'd be better if you had a separate CI server like Jenkins doing your builds, and then deploy from there.

Comment: You can use webhooks to connect your repo to your CI/CD server and automatically build and deploy whenever a commit or PR is merged

Comment: As of now, we are not ready for CI/CD yet.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it, is to build and compile in the local development Workstation, and deploy only the output of the build.

The git repo master branch needs to contain the source code not the only compiled&built one.

You can deploy in the production server using other method rather then the git pull command but if you insist on using it, you can init a new repo in the /build file and pull this repo to the production server.

Comment: I believe you are also thinking not to have the compiled codes into the repo. 
But I think to have it within master for faster deployment rather than duplicating the effort to rebuild the sources, don't you think so?

I like the idea of a separate repo for deployment though.
Thanks!

Comment: For me, it is mandatory to have a repo that contain your source code to track what you are doing during your coding process. The compiled/built repo will not give you alot of information unless you want to track the version where the production code was working perfectly.

Comment: Instead of a compiled/built repo, why not use a build farm to track versions if this is the issue? Such as jenkins, travis or many more.

Comment: Thanks @lordjohncena about the build farm. But as of now, my team is not ready for CI/CD workflow.
Thus, it is not really about tracking the version. But our compiling of source is taking up quite a long time (5 mins and more) to build for production with every possible optimization we can take on webpack to have a compact compiled source.

As mentioned earlier, having the compiled in repo to roll out even on a laptop or onto another server will have been immediate, don't you think so?

Comment: @DavidYew See my answer. Had no more characters left.

Answer (score 1):

If you really can't afford the build farm yet and if it enables the testing or other activites, yeah sure. Test the workflow you describe and see it for yourself, but it's definitely not a good long term practice.

If eventually you're gonna use the CI in your workflow, I would suggest to just start trying to set it up instead of wasting time/money setting up something temporary. Moreover, 5 minutes isn't a big deal trust me.

As a side note: If you would have spent time trying your suggestion instead of writing your SO question and talking with your colleague, you probably would already have figured out the answer yourself.

Comment: Ok, is my assumption now, CI/CD will always rebuild the app from scratch. The estimated time to download all the node_modules (~700Mb) and just on building, without running test will be 15mins. This will be on a low end VPS.

Will need to source a good box/solution to run CI.
Would you have a recommendation, please?

Comment: @DavidYew If you wanna host it yourself as you describe, Jenkins and Travis are the best well-established platforms. Jenkins has plenty of plugins to help you manage your issues such as NodeJS plugin. It is also very fast (also free!!), but has a harder learning curve. Travis on the other hand lacks on those last aspects, but is mainly prefered because of its great documentation and is easier to start with. Also, have you thought about docker support? Other than that you can refer to [this](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/speeding-npm-installs/) to speed-up your node modules download.

Comment: thank you for the helpful link about speeding up node modules installation.